# Ripley wants to leave shuttle to tell team Mother thinks message is a warning -- why not just tell them?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Ripley says to Ash that it is not an SOS but rather a warning. Then she proposes to him that she go out there and he, disingenuously, sort of stammers, What's the point, by the time you get there they'll know if it is a warning or not.

This dialogue may only be in the director's cut, I do not remember this. But the entire exchange makes no sense. If it is a warning, I can't think of a more important thing to tell the away team but after Ash's statement, Ripley just drops the idea. She does not go out there nor does she mention the warning to them which really might have saved Kane from leaning over the egg, which he should not have done anyway.

Comment: I think at this stage, Ash is still a ranking Science Officer that Ripley has to respect. When she drops it, its just because shes not yet sure and assumes Ash has a better idea of the situation - at that point in the narrative. Shes not yet confident, and Ash only just sort of brushes it off

Comment: Pretty sure that part is in the original theatrical release. What makes you think Ash is wrong? By the time Ripley got to them, they would have already encountered any dangers that the warning is about. So Ripley cannot deliver the information soon enough to do any good and would only endanger an additional crew member, herself, by leaving the shuttle.

Comment: I haven't checked the script, but the scene is longer in the novelization https://archive.org/details/alienofficialmov0000alan/page/90/mode/ —although in the end Ash doesn't offer anything more specific than in the film:  ‘What's the point?’ He said it evenly, as though it were the most obvious thing in the world. ‘In the time it would take one of us to get there, they'll know if it’s an operative warning. Am I wrong or am I right?’